# Regex in Qt not matching string it should

Tags: c++, regex, qt

So I have a function, lets call it getMatch.  I wrote a regex to match a string that it receives but the Qt regex engine isn't matching it like I expect it to.

For demonstrations sake, here is some code:

```
bool getMatch()
{
    QString item = "BitwiseAND(Value, Mask)";
    QRegExp rx("\\w+\\([\\w+,\\s]+?\\)", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    return rx.exactMatch(item);
}
```

This should return true every time, but it returns false.

I have tested the regex in online testers, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want [is this](https://regex101.com/r/dIBrog/1):

`\\w+\\((\\w+(?:,\\s)?)+\\)`

your regex is using `[` instead of `(`, but that's a character class, whereas what you are doing is simply *grouping and quantifying*.